# How to get list of release pipeline name in Azure DevOps using rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on script to list all release pipeline names

I found this rest api in Microsoft docs -

GET [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0)

This lists all releases for each release pipeline

Using following pipelines rest api I can get count and info of only build pipelines -

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

Is there similar rest api available like pipeline api to get count and info of all release pipelines (not all releases for each release pipeline)

or Is there way to get all pipelines builds and releases using single rest api ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Definitions - List api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get the count and info of all release pipelines.

`GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.1-preview.4`

There is not a single rest api to get all pipelines builds and releases. If you want to get all pipeline builds. You need to use [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) api. And [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) api for pipeline releases